# HTTP GET request, no "data chunks" received

Tags: node.js, http

Im having a problem with a GET request. The problem is that the data variable is not populated, its empty, but the result code is 200, there are no issues. If I open the link manually in the browser the data is there. Here is my code:

```
class DataHandler {
    constructor(httpRobot, config) {
        DataHandler.prototype.httpRobot = httpRobot;
        DataHandler.prototype.config = config;       
    }
}

class GetData extends DataHandler {
    constructor(httpRobot, config) {
        super(httpRobot, config);
    }
    R(RURL) {
        var data = '';

        super.httpRobot.get(RURL, (resp) => {
            console.log(resp.statusCode)
            resp.on('data', (chunk) => (
                data += chunk
            ))

            resp.on('end', () => {
                data = JSON.parse(data);
            })

        });
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    }
}
```

And then call it with:

```
var httpRobot = require('http')
const GetData = require('./scripts/DataHandling/GetData')(httpRobot, config)
GetData.R('theurl')
```

When I call the R method, I give it the URL and it should return the data, but it doesnt. I have checked and the super.httpRobot does contain the http object. The request is executing, the response code is 200, but data stays empty. Its a JSON object that I am expecting to receive, and I have used this code in the past with success, but I cant figure out why its not working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are not waiting for the chunks to be loaded into data. You have to either use Promise or Callback to wait for the data before returning.

Here is an example using Promise:

```
class GetData extends DataHandler {
  constructor(httpRobot, config) {
    super(httpRobot, config);
  }
  R(RURL) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let data = '';
      super.httpRobot.get(RURL, resp => {
        console.log(resp.statusCode);
        resp.on('data', chunk => (data += chunk));

        resp.on('end', () => {
          data = JSON.parse(data);
          console.log(data);
          resolve(data); //Resolving
        });
      });
    });
  }
}


var httpRobot = require('http');
const GetDataInst = new GetData(httpRobot, {});
GetDataInst.R('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees').then(d=>console.log(d));
```

Comment: How do I get the value out of the .then ? I tried .then(d => return d) but it returns Promise Pending

Comment: yeah so whenever you use promise or callback (basically asynchronous functions) you cannot go back using just synchronous code. so you have to use async await. and promise.

Comment: Whenever you use promise or callback you are basically waiting for the operation to complete but the code is unlocked.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I managed to do that :) I'm having another issue which is not for this specific question, but I'll try my chances: Do you have any idea, why the first time I make this get request, it always returns null, and it starts returning data from the second time onwards? I am using setInterval to call the request every 1 second. I've also used console.time to time the request and the first request is 4ms while the following ones drop down to 0.6ms (local requests)